# Invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \to V$ linear transformation, and let $W$ to be an invariant subspace of $V$. we mark $T_w: W \to W$ the from $T$ to $W$.
Prove that if T is diagonalizable, then $T_w$ is diagonalizable.

How do I start to prove it?
I know that if T is diaognizeable then it's factors are different from each other. but how does that help me here?

Comment: What can you say about the minimal polynomial of $T$ and $T_W$? An endomorphism is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial...?

Comment: Hint : $T$ is diagonalizable iff $V$ is a direct sum of eigenspaces. Show that $W$ is also a direct sum of eigenspaces, using the fact that $W$ is an invariant subspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\;m_T(x)\,,\,\,m_{T_W}(x)\;$ be the minimal poloynomials of $\;T:V\to V\;,\;\;T_W:=T|_W:W\to W\;$ , respectively. Since

$$m_T(T)=0\implies m_T(T)(v)=0\;\;\;\forall\;v\in V\;,\;\;\text{then also}\;\;$$

$$m_T(T)(w)=m_{T_W}(w)=0\;\;\forall\;w\in W\implies m_T(T_W)=0$$

so $\;m_{T_W}(x)|m_T(x)\;$ by minimality of $\;m_{T_W}(x)\;$ .

But this means that since a linear operator on a finite dimensional space is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial splits as the product of different linear factor, since this happens to $\;m_T(x)\;$ it also happens to $\;m_{T_W}(x)\;$ and thus $\;T_W\;$ is diagonalizable.